# How to acces array object in nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

I am getting this req in my req.body . I want to parse the details .Below is my req.

```
"[{\"number\":\"INC0010075\",\"cmdb_ci\":\"hubot-test\",\"short_description\":\"test data for buisness rule 30\",\"category\":\"software\",\"comments\":\"\"}]"
```

I want output like

number:

cmdb_ci:

category:

How do i parse this array object in nodejs. Please help

Comment: You may looking for `JSON.parse()`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` like this:

```
var aJsonArrString = "[{\"number\":\"INC0010075\",\"cmdb_ci\":\"hubot-test\",\"short_description\":\"test data for buisness rule 30\",\"category\":\"software\",\"comments\":\"\"}]"

var aObjList = JSON.parse(aJsonArrString);
for(var i = 0; i < aObjList.length; i++) {
    console.log('number   : ' + aObjList[i].number);
    console.log('cmdb_ci  : ' + aObjList[i].cmdb_ci);
    console.log('category : ' + aObjList[i].category); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use

```
JSON.parse(req.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JSON, I don't know if the escaping \ are coming from your way of logging the value or something so I'll expect it is a valid string to start off.

You can use

```
var my_list = JSON.parse(req.body);
//Access like any other array...
my_list[0].number;
```